# Stuck on setup wizard of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am stuck on this screen [image]

Can't perform any further action. Since I already downloaded an SDK, I downloaded this version [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found reason for this problem, my SDK was corrupted or damaged. My drive were crashed and I have recovered files by recovering tool, that's why files are get damaged and SDK was not working properly.

Then I redownloaded SDK and its running fine.

Answer (score 2):

Actually android studio try to download all the components of sdk, those which you don't have.
So, it can take a lot time, instead you can disable "Downloading Components" at startup:

- Go to the installation directory of Android Studio.
      There you will find a folder named "bin".
      Inside this folder there is a file named "idea.properties".
- Open this file and add the following line to the end of the file:

      disable.android.first.run=true

What this will do is disable the check that Android Studio performs on first run and decides to download all that stuff.

If it asks to save the file at some different place instead of overwriting the original one, please check the access permissions to the file.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: After doing this, it shows "Internal Error. Please report to https://https://code.google.com/p/android/issues" error on startup.

Comment: do a system restart, if you have not edited then, edit the  **idea.properties** file, then start the android studio.

Comment: I have done everything what above mentioned. But same error arise.

Comment: Seems like your android studio is not accepting the config changes. You have to proceed without config change or you can try uninstalling and then reinstalling studio.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Android Studio settings dirs for re-run Setup Wizard.

I my case I removed both

```
C:\Users\bieli\.AndroidStudio4.0
and
C:\Users\bieli\.android
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified custom path to  SDK in previous step?? 
 if you do not download the SDK you have to go through custom settings and then specify path to SDK. 
 you are also needed to configure the path to SDK in your environment variables, if you are using window system.

Comment: Yes, I have specified the custom path of SDK.

Comment: It would have to be setup for the dialog to say "SDK is up to date"

Comment: You can [edit] this post instead of providing 2 answers